# Regular Expression that only takes 3 zeros at most

Tags: regex

This is a part of my CS homework and I have been trying to figure it out for a while now. I am asked to write a regular expression for the language {0,1} where it only accepts strings that have 3 zeros at most. Below is what I came up with but it is not correct as the zeros can be used recursively and go over 3 occurrence. My mind is blank, any input is much appreciated. Thank you

```
1*((0^0|0^1|0^2|0^3)|1*)
```

Edit: I mean 3 zeros in general, They don't have to be in a row, it would've been easy it they were 3 in a row but that's not the case here. Thanks again

Comment: You will need to use negative lookahead.

Comment: I don't think so @anubhava

Comment: When you say at most, does that mean the string can only be `0`, `00` or `000` and nothing else?

Comment: Can you share some inputs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java REGEX to match an exact number of digits in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627988/java-regex-to-match-an-exact-number-of-digits-in-a-string)

Comment: Do you mean only three zeros in total, or only three zeros in a row?

Comment: @kev I can still have more than 3 zeros in the second brackets...

Comment: @anubhava says: _"You will need to use negative lookahead"_ Not true. This can be easily done without any lookaround at all. (But I'm not telling cause its supposed to be homework!)

Comment: @ridgerunner: Sure, there are many ways to solve this problem, `negative lookahead` is just one of them. And yes I didn't post the answer due to home work question.

Comment: @GelaMP FYI added less fancy option.

Answer (score 1):

Without lookaheads, you can use something like this:

```
^(?:[^0]*0){,3}[^0]*$
```

With only 0 and 1s, this is:

```
^(?:1*0){,3}1*$
```

Or, without the `{3}` repetition:

```
^(1*0)?(1*0)?(1*0)?1*$
```

Note that this will allow an empty string.

**Explain Regex**

```
^                        # the beginning of the string
(?:                      # non-capture group (3 times max):
  [^0]*                  #   any character except: '0' (0 or more
                         #   times (matching the most amount
                         #   possible))
  0                      #   '0'
){,3}                     # end of group
[^0]*                    # any character except: '0' (0 or more times
                         # (matching the most amount possible))
$                        # before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         # string
```

Comment: Character ranges like `[^...]`, repetition counts like `{3}`, and `(?:` are probably not allowed. This is CS homework, not Perl homework.

Comment: @Kaz Ah, thanks for that. Added a pared-down option, maybe still too much. :)

Comment: @zx81 Thank you so much, I just have a question. (1*0)? means  any number of ones and only one zero (optional) times tree. Right? So wouldn't that allow more than 3 zeros since we will be going through the whole expression recursively?

Comment: @Gela `(1*0)?` means any [number of ones and only one zero], zero or more times. We copy that three times, either with the `{3}` or by pasting it. There is no recursion here, so it's 3 zeroes max.

Answer (score 0):

`1* 0 1* 0 1* 0 1* 0 1*`  is the RE for at most 3 zeroes in the input set = {0,1}

- = kleene closure

Comment: * (star) = klean closure

Answer (score 0):

The RE for at most 3 0's is 1*.000.1*

Answer (score -1):

Try and break down exactly what the string can be. If it only contains three zeros, and everything else is a `1`, what arrangement can the 1's be in? Can you find separate solutions for 0 zeros, (exactly) 1 zero, exactly 2 zeros and exactly 3 zeros?

A hint is that a string of `0`'s and `1`'s can be seen as a string of single `0`'s, each followed by zero or more `1`'s, or alternatively as a string of single `1`'s each followed by zero or more `0`'s. (Almost - I have missed out a few cases here.)

Comment: Sorry answer section is not meant for asking questions to OP.

Comment: There are rhetorical questions @anubhava. I am trying to get the OP to solve his homework question himself with some help. Better to ask (rhetorical) questions in an answer, than to post an (incorrect) answer in comments as you did.

Comment: If I have to post an answer I will make sure it works unlike posting hints in comments. In any case my comment was for OP not for you.

Comment: @anubhava You should make sure your comment about negative lookahead is correct then. In any case my questions were for OP not for you :)