# REGEX find 6 consecutive numbers in a string, but ignore more than 6 consecutive number groups

Tags: regex, numbers, find, digits

I need to REGEX find 6 consecutive digits in a string[

I need to find exactly 6. ignore sequences if they have more or less than 6

abc12345 - no match, less than 6 consecutive digits

**abc123456 - i need to match only this string and return 123456**

abc1234567 - no match, more than 6 consecutive digits

abc12345678 - no match, morethan 6 consecutive digits

this: **\d{6}** will match first 6 but it will get first 6 from abc12345678 too, which i need to ignore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9628050/62576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you re engine supports lookarounds, you can do:

```
(?<=\D|^)(\d{6})(?=\D|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZEkRs/1/)

Alternatively with negative lookarounds:

```
(?<!\d)(\d{6})(?!\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y9CgYI/1/)